# Sending request params to Freemarker templates (from SPring) ,getting InvalidReference exception

Tags: spring, freemarker

From Spring Controller i am sending some request paramters to be fetched in FTL and be displayed.
But somehow i am landing into InvalidReference Exception.
I am totally new to FTL but i know this doesnt require much setup from spring either.

All other ftls receving request params work but this ftl(searchPage) has only 1 requestParam used .

In Spring Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping("/searchPage") 
public String SearchMethod(@RequestParam String x,@RequestParam(required=false) String op,MapModel m)
{

int myCount=Method_call_returns_int();.
m.addAttribute("Count", myCount);

return "searchPg";
}
```

In FTL ,i import spring.ftl and use
${count!} or ${count} -to fetch dynamic value from controller.

1.
 Exclamation mark -"!" i believe is not-null expression in freemarker.
Somehow count is come to be 'null' in  FTL 
${count} -doesnt throw or display any exception because of ! 
${count!} throws InvalidReferenceExc .

Please correct me here if i misunderstood meaning of !.

2.I debugged java code and see that ModelMap has count added correctly but its only in FTL that not receiving it.

I din't do any other setup explicitly and i dont think its required.

I see other FTLs with similar cases working ,only difference is Object (in my case its int).

Please suggest me what could be the reason .

Answer (score 0):

I believe freemarker is case-sensitive and hence `Count` would not be the same as `count`

Answer (score 0):

Hi all 
Thanks for your replies.Realized it was my mistake caling method at wrong place.Freemarker doesnt need any setup or initialization.